Extract street names within polygon
I work with a list of streetnames in and outside my area of interest. Is there a way to find all streetnames within a given polygon?
I just want the street names so I guess it is geocoding related but not really the actual geocoding way.
The workaround would be the use MMQGIS plugin and just put a dummy address consisting of the street names and the numbers i.e. 1 in it. I rather avoid this because OSM does not always find all addresses.

One way outside of QGIS is https://overpass-turbo.eu/. For example to get addresses within a small polygon in Stockholm: https://imgur.com/ud6PukV

select the streets and look at the name attribute?

You might look at the Overlay Analysis tool.

@IanTurton I do not have a layer with streets and their names. I put the polygon around my area of interest and want to know what streets are within the polygon.
